# Scala : return one of multiple predefined case classes

Tags: scala, scala-collections

we have around 7-8 case classes defined as shown below :

```
case class DocumentReference(res: Option[Seq[Resource]],
                     name: String,
                     description: Option[String],
                     reference:Option[Seq[Reference]])
```

But all these are defined in a separate library and we import them as a jar.
In my code, I am working on a function that can handle multiple of these case classes and one of them will be returned.
Is there a way that I can define my function or a wrapper kind to return one of those predefined case classes?

Thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: It would be better f you provide expected function signature

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a container class that might do what you want. This assumes that there are pre-existing classes `A` and `B`:

```
// Container trait
trait Container {
  type T
  def value: T
}

// Container for each contained type
class ContainerA(a: A) extends Container {
  type T = A
  val value = a
}

class ContainerB(b: B) extends Container {
  type T = B
  val value = b
}

// Companion class to make it easy to create containers
object Container {
  def apply(a: A) = new ContainerA(a)
  def apply(b: B) = new ContainerB(b)
}

// Implicit conversion to and from the Container type
implicit def aToContainer(a: A): Container = Container(a)
implicit def bToContainer(b: B): Container = Container(b)

implicit def aFromContainer(container: ContainerA): A = container.value
implicit def bFromContainer(container: ContainerB): B = container.value

// Sample function using Container
def fun(x: Seq[Container]): Container = {
  x.head match {
    case a: ContainerA => a
    case b: ContainerB => b
  }
}

// Example usage
val a: A = ...
val b: B = ...

fun(List(Container(a), Container(b)))
fun(List[Container](a, b))
fun(List(a, b))
```

It should be clear how this can be extended.

Answer (score -1):

I may have misunderstood your question, but wouldn't this work with using [scala.Either](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/Either.html)?
Looks ugly but something like this should work:

```
 def myMethod : Either[Class1, Either[Class2, Either[...]]] = {...}
```

Or, you could define a common interface/base class that your case classes implement/extend.

Comment: Thanks, but I may not be able extend the case class since they are defined in a third party library

Comment: What about Either then? Alternatively you could also define a custom return type that can hold all 7 to 8 of your case classes.